# How to get the number represented by least-significant non-zero bit efficiently

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

For example, if it is 0xc0, then the result is 0x40,
Since 0xc0 is equal to binary 11000000, the result should be 01000000.

```
public static byte Puzzle(byte x) {
    byte result = 0;
    byte[] masks = new byte[]{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
    foreach(var mask in masks)
    {
      if((x&mask)!=0)
      {
        return mask;
      }
    }
    return 0;
｝
```

This is my current solution. It turns out this question can be solved in 3-4 lines...

Comment: If the input is 0xE0 (1110 0000), what will be the expected result? Still 0x40?

Comment: then the answer is 0x20. 0010 0000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static byte Puzzle(byte x) {
    return (byte) (x & (~x ^ -x));
｝
```

if x is bbbb1000, ~x is BBBB0111  (B is !b)

-x is really ~x+1, (2's complement) so adding 1 to BBBB0111 is BBBB1000

~x ^ -x then is 00001111 & with x gives the lowest 1 bit.

A better answer was supplied by harold in the comments

```
public static byte Puzzle(byte x) {
    return (byte) (x & -x);
｝
```

Comment: Could you explain why -x has the leftmost 4 bits flipped?

Comment: @Tipton, Good question. It's a short hand for ~x+1 if you're using a 2's complement language.  I probably should have used ~x+1 instead.

Comment: Wow. Never even knew about ~ or ^

Comment: This is also equal to `x & -x` ([proof](http://haroldbot.nl/test.html?q=%28x+%26+%28~x+%5E+-x%29%29+%3D%3D+x+%26+-x)) (the intuitive reason is that you can see negation as "keep the low bits up to and including the lowest set bit, complement higher bits")

Comment: @harlod - now I feel foolish for making it so complicated

Answer (score 0):

Maby not the best solution, but you can prepare an array byte[256], store the result for each number and then use it.

Another solution in 1 line:

```
return (byte)((~(x | (x << 1) | (x << 2) | (x << 3) | (x << 4) | (x << 5) | (x << 6) | (x << 7) | (x << 8)) + 1) >> 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hardly a 1-line solution, but at least it doesn't use the hardcoded list of the bits.

I'd do it with some simple bit shifting. Basically, down-shifting the value until the lowest bit is not 0, and then upshifting 1 with the amount of performed shifts to reconstruct the least significant value. Since it's a 'while' it needs an advance zero check though, or it'll go into an infinite loop on zero.

```
public static Byte Puzzle(Byte x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;
    byte shifts = 0;
    while ((x & 1) == 0)
    {
        shifts++;
        x = (Byte)(x >> 1);
    }
    return (Byte)(1 << shifts);
}
```